# How to bulk delete from element collection in jpa

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I'm using jpa 2.0 and I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
public class Folder{

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="folder_files")
    private Set<String> files;      
    // .....
 }
```

Given a file name, I would like to delete all entries where files == *theGivenFileName*. In sql it would be something like this:

```
Delete from folder_files where files = XXX
```

Is there a way to perform this query using criteria-api?
If not, is there a way to perform this query using jpql?

**UPDATE:**
I think my question was not clear enough:
Since jpql uses entities (and not tables) I cannot just perform the sql written above plus since I'm using `@ElementCollection` I don't know how to address this variablr or even deal with it. I would like to delete all entries in that collection (in my case, the files set) which holds a given value, from all entities. Is that possible using jpql or (even better) criteria-api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the like query just the syntax is slightly changed.

```
query = em.createQuery("SELECT i FROM Item i WHERE UPPER(i.name) LIKE :keyword ");
query.setParameter("keyword", "%" + keyword.toUpperCase() + "%");
```

You can read more on following link,

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=423742

Updated:

@Noam you can do it: Like in Criteria API

```
List cats = sess.createCriteria(Cat.class)
    .add( Restrictions.like("name", "Fritz%") )
    .add( Restrictions.between("weight", minWeight, maxWeight) )
    .list();
```

Kindly read more on it at following link:

http://ctpconsulting.github.com/query/1.0.0.Alpha3/criteria.html

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply - but do you know how to perform it using criteria-api?

Comment: I've updated my question. Please take a look, and I would happy if you could still help me.

Answer (score 3):

The Delete FROM clause requires an Entity, so there is no way to delete from an element collection from what I understand.

You can use a native SQL query, or you can map the element collection as a OneToMany to an Entity instead.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Why do you think there is no way of using jpql? can you give me a reference that will support that?
BTW - I've update my quesion.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done. Via JPQL it does not work because DELETE statement can only be applied to entities. Excerpt from JPA 2.0 specification:

> Bulk update and delete operations apply to entities of a single entity
>   class (together with its subclasses,if any).
>   ...
>   delete_statement ::= delete_clause [where_clause]
>   delete_clause ::= DELETE FROM entity_name [[AS] identification_variable]

Also it doesn't work via Criteria API. [CriteriaQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html) supports only selecting - not updates or removals.

You have to go for native SQL.